# Swap long and short description

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2

Is there an easy way to swap the long and short descriptions in the mysql database for a magento 2.2.0 installation for all products?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a New File in Magento Root name it 'swap-product-desc.php'
2. Add Below Code in that file and run it by url : 'your-site-url/swap-product-desc.php'.

   ```
   <?php 

   use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
   include('app/bootstrap.php');

   // add bootstrap
   $bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
   $object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

   $app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
   $app_state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 

   $productCollection = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();

   foreach($productCollection as $product){

      $productObject     =  $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());

      try{
        $productDesc       = $productObject->getDescription();
        $productShortDesc  = $productObject->getShortDescription();

        $productObject->setDescription($productShortDesc);
        $productObject->setShortDescription($productDesc);

        $productObject->save();

        echo "Product ID :".$productObject->getId()." DESCRIPTIONS Swapped Successfully.<br>";
      }
      catch(Exception $e)
     {
       // errro in exception/code
       print_r('Error in Product Desc Swapping For Product ID : '.$productObject->getId().' : '.$e->getMessage().'<br>');
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome reply.. But for some reason it didn't quite work? The script ran for several hours (about 10K products in shop), and outputted each products as it should. But all the descriptions are still all under the short description field.

Comment: Ok I will Update the Code Tommorow.

Comment: Any ide what could be wrong with this? Looks ok to me.

Comment: did you have an idea why the script isn't swapping the descriptions? It ran for several hours and posted ID after each item was processed, but no descriptions was changed though.

Comment: Yes it is actually Swapping product description but it is doing it for Default store view if you swap store view in backend you can see that Descriptions are swapped.

Comment: You are right. Has 3 stores there, so haven't noticed it changed for the first one on store view level.
Can I add a link to make it work on a global scope?